# ALGObot, What error is causing this to only fall through ".......sold for a profit"?

Tags: python, api, kucoin

```
def execute_doge_musktrade():


###Due to technical difficulties in instanteous limit orders (delay has been up to 6seconds)
###I have decided to instanteously order via market order and independently
#set the dogecoin price for monitoring
doge_data = get_price("DOGE-USDT")
doge_price = doge_data['price']
doge_price = float(doge_price)
symbol = "DOGE-USDT"
size = 1
client.create_market_order(symbol=symbol, side="buy", size=size)
print(f"1 dogecoin was successfully purchased at {doge_price}")
##SET to Text you the purchase order and then after sale the sale order

##Then we want to monitor the price of said token, and we want to determine what percentage of profits/losses we want to accept
desired_take_profit = 1.005
take_profit_target = doge_price * desired_take_profit
desired_stop_loss = 0.9975
stop_loss_target = doge_price * desired_stop_loss
print(take_profit_target, stop_loss_target)

doge_coin_not_sold = True
while doge_coin_not_sold:
    doge_monitor = get_price("DOGE-USDT")
    doge_monitor_price = doge_monitor['price']
    doge_monitor_price = float(doge_monitor_price)
    if doge_monitor_price <= stop_loss_target:
        doge_coin_not_sold = False
        client.create_market_order(symbol=symbol, side="sell", size=size)
        account_balance = doge_musk_check_balance()
        print(f"Dogecoin was sold for a 0.05% profit @{doge_monitor_price}")
        print(f"Account Balance:{account_balance}\n")
        return ("Success")
    ####If the take profit target is hit; trigger dogecoinsold, client.kucoin SELL, and print to the console
    if doge_monitor_price >= take_profit_target:
        doge_coin_not_sold = False
        client.create_market_order(symbol=symbol, side="sell", size=size)
        account_balance = doge_musk_check_balance()
        print(f"Dogecoin was sold for a 0.03% loss @{doge_monitor_price}")
        print(f"Account Balance: {account_balance}\n")
        return("Failure")
time.sleep(0.5)
```

[FROM CONSOLE]
These are trials that I have run:
[FROM CONSOLE]

BEGINNING BALANCE: 20.98360669
How many times should we run this data: 25
1 dogecoin was successfully purchased at 0.13936
0.1400568 0.1390116
Dogecoin was sold for a 0.05% profit @0.139
Account Balance:20.98188833

1 dogecoin was successfully purchased at 0.139
0.13969499999999999 0.1386525
Dogecoin was sold for a 0.05% profit @0.13865
Account Balance:20.980210890000002

1 dogecoin was successfully purchased at 0.13863
0.13932314999999998 0.13828342500000002
Dogecoin was sold for a 0.05% profit @0.13827
Account Balance:20.97839392

1 dogecoin was successfully purchased at 0.13827
0.13896134999999998 0.13792432500000001

Comment: Hi Infinite Grasp, when posing questions you might want to start with the core of the problem you are trying to solve and only afterwards post the code. Also, the long numbers are irritating. Questions can become confusing and thus not easily solvable if there is too much text clutter. Nice though that you answered your own question!

Comment: Funny thing is I did not solve it. It was working for some reason for a while and it not working again. Im starting to think there is an issue with the input/output functions themselves

Comment: What happens exactly when your code doesn't work?